# image view displaying very tiny image on iPhone device

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview

i have an image view (added through storyboard),when we run app it showing big(required size) image,but when running on real device(iPhone)the image size is very tiny.i have double checked,the name of image is correct,and no case sensitive problem.i'm not able find the reason,can any one know about this please help me....

Comment: did you checked in build phases -> copy bundle resources, its properly added or not? I think your problem in build phases check it once again.

Comment: it is in copy bundle resources properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 2x image in your bundle is corrupted, sometimes it happens. Please remove 2x image and add again. Do project clean up and run again. it will sometimes work.